# Add numbers from list of elements. O(1) Logic c++

Tags: algorithm

I have large array with random number stored in it. I want to create a function which returns the sum of numbers from given starting and end position in O(1) time.
Is there another method of storing number to achieve O(1) ?

Comment: There is no way to add up `N` numbers in less than `O(N)` time. It seems that you should store the sum of the random numbers in a separate variable, but without seeing any code at all it's hard to be sure if that is applicable to your situation. Please when you are asking questions about code you have written, post the code as well. That should be obvious.

Comment: To sum all numbers within a range you would need to visit each number within that range at least once to add it to a total sum. So the best complexity I see you getting is O(N).

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you have to compute lots of different sum with several range you can maybe pre-compute an equivalent to this for array https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table

Comment: @john there is no code for now as such. Still it can be something like this

vector<unsigned char> dummyBuffer;

 for (int i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++)
 {
  dummyBuffer.push_back(rand()%255);
 }


int Sum=0;
Sum = CalculateSum(dummyBuffer.data(),start,end);   // sharing the address of vectror, start and end variables are int

Comment: @user8415398 Why 255? If you want a number from 0 to 255 then it should be `rand()%256`

Comment: @user8415398 It is impossible to write `CalculateSum` in `O(1)` time. There's no magic here, the time taken to sum `N` numbers is `O(N)`. Whatever problem you are trying to solve you are going to have to find a different way to do it. It's possible that you've misunderstood the problem you have been given.

Comment: @John its a test and person who have given me this test told me that O(1) solution exist for this

Comment: @user8415398 Either they are wrong, or you have misunderstood the question or you have not described it accurately here. Adding up N numbers cannot be O(1).

Comment: @John Yeah can be true. If i can share you the test may be you can have a look at it ?

Comment: @user8415398 Sure, i'm intrigued

Comment: @John can you share me your email id. Test content is too long to put in comment.

Comment: @user8415398 Sorry sharing email is not possible. You can edit the question. Clcik the edit link beneath the question.

Comment: @user8415398 Sorry no, this is a public forum, edit the question to include the test.

Comment: @john Sorry don't feel right to put the test on public forum. More details i could give you is its related to image processing. So basically I have to read a gray scale pixel buffer (hence 0 to 255 values only) and send it to SumPixel class and class will create its own copy of buffer and perform different operations like calculate Sum and Average of pixels. They haven't told me to capture actual pixel hence i am creating my own dummy buffer and passing to class. I am not very familiar with image processing techniques and the way they have given me the test, i feel its purely c++ based.

Comment: @user8415398 Crucial to how efficient you can make this is the details of the operations you must support. In terms of assymptopic complexity the language is irrelevant.

Comment: Solution: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/submatrix-sum-queries/

Answer (score -1):

It’s not possible to make a O(1) code, to get the sum of numbers.

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but as an answer you should give some good arguments or even a proof of it.